# ASP .net MVC 4 - RenderAction Throttling CPU

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cpu

[image]

When I call an child action like this:

```
<ul class="media-list" id="newsfeed-container">
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                Html.RenderAction("NewsFeedItem", "Post",
                    new DAL.Models.Post()
                    {
                        ID = item.ID,
                        DateTime = item.DateTime,
                        Message = item.Message,
                        HasPhoto = item.HasPhoto,
                        User = item.User,
                        Photos = item.Photos,
                        IsAllowComment = item.IsAllowComment,
                        IsVisible = item.IsVisible
                    });
            }
        }
    </ul>
```

The ***item*** is from ***dbContext.Posts.Tolist()*** ( It's about 78 record in database )

This is ***NewsNfeedItem*** action

```
// Display each feed in newsfeed
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult NewsFeedItem(Post model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

When i run my application the IIS Express Worker Prcess CPU is very high.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Use return PartialView(model);

Comment: Glad you got it working, i've added this as an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PartialView()`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult NewsFeedItem(Post model)
{
        return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it not work. I will check the codes inside the view files.

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify your main view as below :

```
<ul class="media-list" id="newsfeed-container">
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_NewsFeedItemPartialView", item);
        }
    }
</ul>
```

And then you will remove the NewsFeedItem action wbecause it will be unusual

But you will have to put your model in the top of your _NewsFeedItemPartialView View like that :

```
@model namespace.Models.UsedModel
```